# Creating a 2-D net array in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga

I was trying to write a program using 2-D net array. But when the code is checked it shows an error (expecting ';', found '['). How should I declare a 2d net array and how to use it ?

Below is the simple code for I written for verification (shows the above error).

```
module bin(a);
input [0:1] a[0:2];
endmodule
```

Comment: 2D ports may be a SystemVerilog thing, so you need to tell your simulator you are using SV syntax.  You can probably add something like `-sv` to your command.

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays and unpacked arrays as ports are not supported in Verilog. The only arrays Verilog supports in port lists are simple packed arrays (aka vectors).

SystemVerilog does support multidimensional arrays in all variations. All modern Verilog simulators are actually SystemVerilog simulators with backward comparability.

The preferred method to differentiate Verilog and SystemVerilog files is with the file extension. SystemVerilog files should use `.sv` while Verilog uses the the traditional `.v`.

Alternativly, simulators have an option to force `.v` files to be compiled as SystemVerilog. Several use `-sv` as the compiler option but some use a differnt identifier so you will need to refer to your manual or help-file. The disadvantage to this is approach happens when you are mixing legacy verilog files that happen to use variable/net names that became keep words in SystemVerlog. Using the proper file extension mitigates this risk by compiling each file based in the extension name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an unpacked array in ports. Please note that Verilog is a Hardware Description Language, not a Software Language. Only those things will be supported in Verilog, which can be mapped into real hardware.

> You can have a packed array in port, not an unpacked array.

Packed array, can be thought of as a bunch of wires in simplest terminology. However, unpacked arrays are not stored consecutively and hence they can't be treated as simple bunch of wires.

Answer (score 0):

```
module bin(a);
input a[2:0][1:0];
endmodule
```

This should work, since it is a packed array dimension.Or else you can use a bus to represent your inputs and break it.

```
module bin(a);
input a[5:0];

  wire [1:0] a1, a2, a3;
  assign {a1,a2,a3} = a;
endmodule
```

Comment: You have your packed and unpacked declarations confused. `input a[2:0][1:0];` is a double unpacked array where as `input [2:0][1:0] a;` would be a double packed array; neither are supported by Verilog. `input a[5:0];` is a unpacked arrays and not supported by Verilog. Verilog only supports simple vector arrays in port-lists (ex: `input [5:0] a;`). SystemVerilog does support these complex arrays in port-lists, however the OP is asking for Verilog.